# How to select the nth-child of h2 elements in div

Tags: javascript, css

I am using the jquery plugin "hopscotch" [Hopscotch](http://linkedin.github.io/hopscotch/)

I am also using an "easy responsive tabs" plugin which converts tabs to accordian style to allow for responsiveness.

Hopscotch allows one to write a stepped tutorial that relies on each step having a "target" defined. The targets are defined on the plugin page to be:

**target [STRING/ELEMENT/ARRAY]** - id of the target DOM element or DOM element itself. It is also possible to define an array of several targets. If an array is provided, Hopscotch will use the first target that exists on the page and disregard the rest.

Therefore I want to set up an array for my target so that it gets the right element regardless of whether the DOM is showing tabs or accordian.

The HTML in accordian looks like this:

```
<div id="profileFormTabs" style="display: block; width: 100%; margin: 0px;">

<div class="resp-tabs-container">
    <h2 class="resp-accordion" role="tab" aria-controls="tab_item-0">
    // content here
    </h2>
    <h2 class="resp-accordion" role="tab" aria-controls="tab_item-1">
    // content here
    </h2>
    <h2 class="resp-accordion resp-tab-active" role="tab" aria-controls="tab_item-2">
    // content here
    </h2>
</div>

</div>
```

My first target looks like this:

```
target: ['profileFormTabs', '.resp-tabs-container > h2'],
```

This correctly targets the id of profileFormTabs (if they are viewing tabs) and it also correctly targets the first h2 element if they are looking at the DOM and it is in accordian.

My second target is configured as:

```
target: ['#profileFormTabs ul > li:nth-child(2n)', '.resp-tabs-container > h2:nth-of-type(1)'],
```

This also works for tabs. BUT, it doesn't work for accordian.

I've tried:

```
.resp-tabs-container > h2:nth-child(2n)
...
.resp-tabs-container > h2 > h2
...
document.getElementsByClassName("resp-tabs-container").nextSibling
etc
```

But to no avail.

I can't add id's to all the elements in the accordian without changing the 'easy responsive tabs' plugin which I would rather not do (so it is easy to update when new updates are released).

I've had no luck using jQuery as my target selector. So I wondered if this is possible using purely javascript / css ?

Many thanks

Comment: You unclosed `<h2>` tags are kind of confusing.

Comment: Unsure as to why you can't give them all id's

Comment: If you want to target the _second_ `h2`, then that should be `nth-of-type(2)`, not 1. And the `2n` version selects every second, fourth and so on, so if you want to target only _one_ element specifically, then going with multiples of `n` is the wrong way.

Comment: @Musa, corrected the h2's now thanks. ZenStein, I can only do that by changing the "easy responsive tabs" plugin which I would rather not do so that it is easier to update when new updates are released. CBroe, thank you for the info. I didn't realise that :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `document.querySelectorAll('h2:nth-child(1) ul li:nth-child(2)')` for example.

Comment: The selector is an array in my original post so it is either the h2 or the li. h2:nth-child doesn't work unfortunately. I'm leaning towards using jQuery to inject id elements on to the h2 elements and then using those to select with... but wondered if you had any other ideas before I go down that route? Thank you :-)

Comment: can you provide real example in some jsfiddle? i'm sure we can figure it out

Answer (score 0):

A big thanks for the all the answers. I have altered the plugin directly in order to achieve what I needed.

Thanks again :-)